# EXC_BAD_ACCES drawing shadow

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting, cgcontext

I am trying to add a shadow to my UIView, but in my drawRect method I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
(I am using ARC)

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGColorRef lightColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8].CGColor;

    CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4].CGColor;   

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Draw shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-5, 0), 10, shadowColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, _coloredBoxRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

**Error Message:**
Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

**Line:** `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);`

When I change this line to:

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8] setFill];
```

I get the same error but on this line:

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-5, 0), 10, shadowColor);
```

**Update**
I finally resolved the issue by changing:

CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4].CGColor;

to

float components[4] = {0, 0, 0, 1.0/3.0};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorCreate( colorSpace, components);

**The eventual (working) code:**

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    float components[4] = {0, 0, 0, 1.0/3.0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorCreate( colorSpace, components);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-5, 0), 10, shadowColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);

    [[UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8] setFill];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: Post the exact error message here.

Comment: The error message won't really help, but for your comfort (see edit).

Comment: Your debugger should at least tell you which line is crashing.

Comment: drawRect is called by iOS itself when drawing the UIView.

Comment: It is crashing on CGContextSetFillColorWithColor

Comment: Can you try a `CGColorRetain()` around your `[UIColor ...].CGColor` lines? `CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorRetain([UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4].CGColor);` just to make sure the colors are (maybe over-) retained.

Comment: Failing that: `UIColor *shadowUIColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4];` and then for the layers use `shadowUIColor.CGColor` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any reason why that would crash, but try setting your color using this code instead of using a CGColorRef. If it doesn't fix the crash at least you'll know that line wasn't the problem:

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8] setFill];
```

Comment: now it crashes on CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-5, 0), 10, shadowColor);

Comment: And what happens if you remove that line?

Comment: What if you create you shadow Color using one of the CGColorCreate... methods and release it after you do the drawing. It shouldn't be neccesary and it's more of a hassle but again it should help diagnose if the issue is really related to that line.

Comment: FYI, that shadow color is now being leaked. You should call CGColorRelease(shadowColor); after you're done with it.

Comment: I don't think so. ARC inserts cocoa style [... release] and [... autorelease] statements for you, but it doesn't know how to clean up Core Foundation objects, so objects created using XXCreate... still need to be released using XXRelease when you're done with them. You're also leaking the CGColorSpaceRef.

Answer (score 5):

The `UIColor` may not make it into an autorelease pool when ARC's enabled. If it is not put in a pool and immediately released, the `CGColor`s you reference (lightColor, shadowColor) would also have been deallocated by the time you pass it because they are held/owned by the `UIColor`, and no measure has been taken to ensure that these (non-`NSObject`) references remain valid beyond that scope.

I can't reproduce your exact issue, but I can reproduce it using:

```
CGColorRef shadowColor =
  [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4].CGColor;
```

when run on the sim v5.0.

Have you posted the exact example? What OS version are you running on? Does it happen in all OS versions? Perhaps you should have a peek at the asm.

Comment: I hope not! That would be a horrible bug with ARC if so.

Comment: @Nick yeah an ARC transition could break a good amount of code, but this is how it works.

Comment: Three20 table view is also crashing since iOS 5 with shadow enabled.

Comment: @mc007 has anybody come up with an explanation for it?

Comment: There is a discussion going on but sorry me, I can't remember where nad I had no time to find it back.

Answer (score 3):

Alternately you can tell the compiler to add your `UIColor` objects to the autorelease pool and not immediately release them.

```
UIColor * __autoreleasing lightUIColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8];
CGColorRef lightColor =  lightUIColor.CGColor;

UIColor * __autoreleasing shadowUIColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4];
CGColorRef shadowColor = shadowUIColor.CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will satisfy ARC:

```
UIColor *lightColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8];
...
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor.CGColor);
```

The reason for a crash that ARC deallocated interim UIColor* object just right after you created it.