# Assigning an existing CGColor to a CGColor property works in iOS Simulator, not iOS device. Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, exc-bad-access

I know how to fix the problem that I am about to outline, however, I am a bit baffled as to why the code scenario works in the iOS simulator but not on my iPad.

I have a method that checks various properties, and then sets the background color of a `CALayer` depending on the state of a property.  The following code is similar to my method of color assignment:

```
//This will be the CALayer BGColor...
CGColor c = UIColor.blueColor.CGColor; //Blue is the default
switch (myState)
{
    case state_one:
        c = UIColor.greenColor.CGColor;
        //... more code ...
        break;
    case state_two:
        c = UIColor.redColor.CGColor;
        //... more code ...
        break;
    case state_three: //multiple cases are like the state_three case.
        //Other code, but I don't need to assign the color.  Blue works...
}

myCALayer.backgroundColor = c; //Oh-noes!!! Here we get the dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPad
//...more code dealing with the layer.
```

The code above works without trouble in the Simulator.  However, when I run the application on my iPad, it crashes at the `backgroundColor` assignment.

I can fix this by getting rid of the `CGColor` variable and assigning the background color from directly within my switch/case statement, and that's what I'm planning on doing.

However, I am curious.  Why would this work in one environment and not the other?

**UPDATE**

Couple things.  First, it's worth mentioning that this is an ARC project, using Xcode 4.2, targeting iOS 5 devices.  Also, my color assignement code isn't entirely what it looks like because I have a series of defines that I use to set these colors because they are referenced all throughout my application.

This is what a few of the `#define` statements looks like:

```
#define BLUE  [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0 green:80.0/255.0 blue:150.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor
#define GREEN (UIColor.blueColor.CGColor)
//...and there are about 6 other colors
```

I tried to simplify my code because the compiler *should* replace the refs to my refs to my defines.  Still, it's worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Did you make sure to include the QuartzCore framework in each build?

Comment: Mine won't even build with your `CGColor` maybe you meant `CGColorRef`

Comment: I've added the framework, and referenced the headers from within the code file that's making this assignment.

Comment: @Paul.s-- I am using ARC.  I wonder if that makes a difference.  I removed the variable, so I'll have to add it back in to test.

Comment: Is your `myCGLayer` variable still around? I'm not sure it's the colours that are causing the issue

Comment: @paul.s- It should be.  I'm actually iterating over all sublayers.  This case statement is taking place from within the `for` loop.  The layer being referenced is defined in the `for` loop as `for (CALayer* l in UnitDisplay.layer.sublayers)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my hunch: It's possible that the `UIColor` that created it (and held its only reference) has been destroyed before you pass the `CGColor`. Since `CGColorRef`'s reference counting is not handled for you under ARC, the color would be a dangling reference if the `UIColor` that held it were destroyed before you use the `CGColor`.

ARC has an optimization where "autoreleased" objects may never be added to an autorelease pools, and instead, `released` after the objc object is no longer referenced. This is a combination of three things:

1. The compiler version and options you use. No surprise, the compiler adds the reference counting, and there are variations for this.
2. The ObjC Runtime. The runtime may utilize thread local data. Naturally, this can include your stack. If you read into the details of how an object may bypass an autorelease pool, this should be clearer.
3. The libraries you use (including system libraries and frameworks). As the compiler and runtimes are updated, the libraries may use ARC, or they may use different runtime calls to execute the program.

Knowing that, I suspect this program would rectify the problem:

```
UIColor * c = UIColor.blueColor; //Blue is the default
switch (myState) {
    case state_one:
        c = UIColor.greenColor;
        //... more code ...
        break;
    case state_two:
        c = UIColor.redColor;
        //... more code ...
        break;
    case state_three: //multiple cases are like the state_three case.
        //Other code, but I don't need to assign the color.  Blue works...
}

myCGLayer.backgroundColor = c.CGColor;
//...more code dealing with the layer.
```

In more detail, there are number of ways the compiler and *the objc runtime* can interpret and execute your program. This means that this problem could affect you when you change compiler versions, or when the runtime (OS) is updated. It can also happen as the libraries you use are updated or built with different versions or compiler settings. For example: If the library switches to ARC along the way, it may use a different runtime calls, or the calls may utilize thread local data differently if the compiler injected calls are updated.

Details about the ARC spec as it relates to the runtime can be found here:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#runtime

---

A similar problem was seen here:

[EXC_BAD_ACCES drawing shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974910/exc-bad-acces-drawing-shadow/8976180#8976180)

Comment: Ignore the message I just deleted.  Magic! This has fixed the problem.  Are there significant differences in the way the QuartzCore manages memory on OSX from iOS?  This isn't the first time I've seen minor, memory management oddities between the two, but this has certainly been the oddest.

Comment: @RLH It's not Quartz - it's to do with ARC and the compiler (that's my hunch -- I don't use ARC in real projects yet, and have not read the latest implementation of the objc runtime to confirm this @100%). The runtime uses thread local storage in some cases; objects which *would* be autoreleased in MRC may not ever be added to an autorelease pool. Instead, the compiler would add what would result in a release message under some runtimes (naturally, this would happen after you're finished using it). I've added a link to my answer for some more details regarding its implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link and I've marked this as the answer because I doubt there is a direct (discernible) answer, unless someone around here works with the Apple proprietary code for these frameworks or compilers.  Your article looks rather deep-- I'll check it out this weekend.

Comment: @RLH one can determine the cause, without going to Apple, using assembly + debugger. you may also find some answers in the open source components. you're welcome

Answer (score 9):

Because of ARC the color is released too early in the end of the method.

i use: **CGColorRetain**

```
CGColorRef whiteColor = CGColorRetain([UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0
                                         blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor);
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your instance `myCGLayer` us derived from, but I'll take a shot and say it's not derived from CGLayer, because CGLayer doesn't have a `backgroundColor` property. So I'm guessing (again), the parameter passed should be of type UIColor and not CGColor. CGColor is derived from class CFType. UIColor is derived from NSObject. They shouldn't be interchangeable. If my guesses are right, I'm surprised it works in the simulator.

Don't slap me too hard if my guesses are wrong.

Comment: They probably meant CALayer. They actually said CALayer in the description.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that was my mistake.  I typed in all of that sample code, so, no cut-and-paste.  Chuck is right-- this is a `CALayer`.  I've updated my variable in the sample to reflect this.

Comment: That would make a difference (if the real code doesn't have that sort of typo).