# Quartz 2D Drawing Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I don't know why this stopped working, but this chunk of code is crashing my device when I try drawing any part of it. I'm new to core graphics so any pointers or suggestions would be a great help. Thanks!

```
// Style
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Colors
CGColorRef fillBox = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGColorRef fillBoxShadow = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:77.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

CGRect box = CGRectMake(5, 5, self.frame.size.width - 10, self.frame.size.height - 10);
// Shadow
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 1.0, fillBoxShadow);
CGContextAddRect(context, box);
CGContextFillPath(context);
// Box
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillBox);
CGContextAddRect(context, box);

CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is using ARC, then these two lines might be part of your problem:

```
CGColorRef fillBox = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGColorRef fillBoxShadow = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:77.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

ARC is releasing the UIColor object and thus the CGColorRef. You need to retain the CGColorRef and then release it when you are done with it.

I would write the code something like this:

```
UIColor *fillBox = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *fillBoxShadow = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:77.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

and then use fillBox.CGColor and fillBoxShadow.CGColor later on in the method.

Comment: It's not released immediately, but at the end of the runloop : `colorWithRed...` is a factory method that returns an autoreleased object. They are released at the end of an `@autorelease` block, or after the runloop iteration. So that's not where the problem comes from.

Comment: Beg to differ. ARC will release the UIColor objects before the `CGRect box = CGRectMake(...);` code. I ran into this myself when converting an existing project to ARC many moons ago...

Comment: Negative. Just tried on a piece of code of mine: `CGColorRef white = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor; CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect); CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, white); CGContextAddPath(ctx, _bezier.CGPath); CGContextFillPath(ctx);` and it works perfectly in ARC.

Comment: The UIColor object just happens to be in memory at the same place. If you enable NSZombie, you will see the object has been released. See http://blog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218664/assigning-an-existing-cgcolor-to-a-cgcolor-property-works-in-ios-simulator-not

Comment: I don't see any problem with zombies enabled, and the static analyzer doesn't tell me this is potentially dangerous. Even if you're right, that isn't the cause of the crash.

Comment: To my knowledge, the `CGColor` should be retained past the lifetime of the `UIColor` because the property's value is retained/autoreleased on every call.

Comment: It's possible that this was fixed in the newly-released tools and/or SDK, because this used to be VERY common. I haven't checked, though.

Comment: Follow-up: I have just checked with the iOS 6.1 SDK in Xcode 4.6. It seems to work now (at least in Simulator) with the formerly-broken code. I tested with and without zombies enabled. I'm not sure whether this is a framework change or an ARC behavior change; I'll leave that for somebody more willing to read assembly code than me to discover.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
CGContextAddRect(context, box);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Try using `CGContextFillRect`.

You can't fill a path you haven't added to the context beforehand.

Note: you could do

```
CGContextAddPath(context, [UIBezierPath pathWithRect:box].CGPath);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

but that's a bit overkill compared to just filling a rect.

(Not sure about the `pathWithRect:` syntax, but it exists.)

Comment: `CGContextAddRect` adds the rectangle to the context's current path. The two means of doing that are equivalent. I do agree, though, that `CGContextFillRect` is simpler and therefore better in the absence of anything else to be painted in the same fill.