# What is the equivalent to [NSPatternColor CGColor] in OS X 10.7?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I have the following code that works fine in OS X 10.8:

```
[viewLayer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"editbackground.png"]].CGColor];
```

But when I used it on OS X 10.7 I get the following crash:

```
-[NSPatternColor CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Does anyone know how I can make the code work on 10.7?

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with early release (but that could explain lots of other issues I have seen!). CGColor is only supported from 10.8 onwards according to the NSColor class reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an ARC early release issue. Try splitting into two lines with an `CGColorRef` intermediate.

```
CGColorRef color = [NSImage imageNamed:@"editbackground.png"]].CGColor;
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:color];
CGColorRelease(color);
```

[See SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9219307/451475)